# Firebug: How to see attached events of an object?

Tags: javascript, firebug

I've attached some events to some divs using `addEventListener`. But where can I see the events in Firebug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's probably worth mentioning that Firebug 1.12 introduced `getEventListeners(target)`.  The Firebug wiki page for it is [here](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/GetEventListeners), and there's a very useful blog post about it [here](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/planet-mozilla/firebug-tip-geteventlisteners-command/).

(Firebug 1.12 was only released in August 2013, so the answer to this question was right when it was originally posted.)

However, there are a couple of caveats for `getEventListeners`:

First off, it won't work if you pass it a jQuery object; pass it a normal DOM object instead.  (Perhaps this is obvious, but it caught me out!)

Secondly, I've found that `getEventListeners` doesn't always work if I run it before all code on a page has loaded.  I'm not sure exactly when it does and doesn't work, but I've certainly seen a situation like this:

```
>>> getEventListeners(document.getElementById('elementid'))
ReferenceError: getEventListeners is not defined
>>> $._data(document.getElementById('elementid'), "events");
Object { click=[1]}
```

As you can see, the "longhand" method (from the SO post linked to in the answer) can retrieve the event, but `getEventListeners` is showing up as not defined.  This error is different to the return value you get if `getEventListeners` runs but reports that an object has no listeners, so I'd say you can use `getEventListeners` without fear, as it'll be obvious if it's not yet available!

Answer (score 12):

If you are using jQuery, then install [FireQuery](http://firequery.binaryage.com/), it shows all bound events on the HTML DOM panel per element.  Very useful addition.

Comment: Additionally it shows up any data you store, and provides a "jqueryify" button on the console for injecting the current version of jQuery on to the page you are viewing, which is very useful.

Comment: Thanks for this. FireQuery is an excellent tool and well worth intsalling for any web developer using jQuery with Firebug.

Comment: It looks like it stopped working at some point... I use the newest version of jQuery and I could not see anything with that extension.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think Firebug has good functionality for that. You might wanna look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node/447106#447106).